# SetValue on Propertyinfo Target Exception object doesn't match target type error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set a value for a property but I'm getting a "Target Exception object doesn't match target type error all the time".

The properties class

```
class WizardProperties
{
    public int IncIncidentType { get; set; }
}
```

Code snippet where I try to set the property value

```
 public void _wizardControl_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardCommandButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in e.Page.Controls)
        {
            WizardProperties props = new WizardProperties();
            SearchLookUpEdit slue = new SearchLookUpEdit();
               foreach (var property in props.GetType().GetProperties())
               {
                   if (!(c is Label))
                   {
                       if (property.Name == c.Name)
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("Matchhh!!");

                           if (c is SearchLookUpEdit)
                           {
                              slue = (SearchLookUpEdit)c;
                           }
                           PropertyInfo info = props.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);

                           int type = Convert.ToInt32(slue.EditValue);

                           info.SetValue(property,type,null);

                       }
                   }
               }
         }

    }
```

The properties are declared in a separate class, the error occurs at: info.SetValue(property,type,null). I added null as third parameter (solution found while searching for this error) but this didn't work for me. The type variable has a valid int.
How to fix the setValue line?

***EDIT:*** Simply changed

```
 info.SetValue(property,type,null);
```

To

```
 info.SetValue(props,type,null);
```

Fixed the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to set the value of the property on the `PropertyInfo` object that represent the property you want to set rather than on `props` which is the instance of the class. You are also retrieving the `PropertyInfo` a second time while looping through the properties of `props` so I have removed that. I am also assuming you are actually going to do something with `props` once you get this code to work. Try below.:

```
foreach (Control c in e.Page.Controls)
{
    WizardProperties props = new WizardProperties();
    SearchLookUpEdit slue = new SearchLookUpEdit();
    foreach (var property in props.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (!(c is Label) && property.Name == c.Name)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Matchhh!!");

             if (c is SearchLookUpEdit)
             {
                 slue = (SearchLookUpEdit)c;
             }

             int type = Convert.ToInt32(slue.EditValue);

             property.SetValue(props,type,null);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I found at that trying to set the value on the property was causing the error. I will mark your answer as accepted because you also optimized my code. Thanks for that.